# How to get specific information from SVN?

Tags: svn

I am using Windows and svn. When I query svn with command line using the command - svn log `http://your_repo/subdirectory/file -r 285:0 -l 1`

I get an output which looks something like below -

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r300 | jObrien | 2014-10-01 14:00:00 -0100 (Wed, 01 Oct 2014) | 1 line

PROJ-125: Make the window bigger...etc...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I make svn only return the svn revision (preferably without the r), time stamp (2014-10-01 14:00:00) and project story (PROJ-125) ? Do I have to use windows cmd utilities to extract the relevant info or is there some svn command which will automatically extract only the information I want ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the `--xml` argument to `svn log`, you can then look at the 
`<revision>` and `<date>` elements.  It's going to take a little more doing to parse the `<msg>` elment to get the JIRA ID.  Parsing the xml is going to be way better than the normal commandline output.

Answer (score -1):

Svn returns data which is easy to parse. You could install gnuwin32 and benefit from Unix command line parsing. Python would also be an easy duct tape solution

Answer (score -1):

In short: no, there isn't. You can limit the output to just the data line (without the log message) by adding the `-q`/`/q` flag to your query. If you want to extract just the revision, you need some other means of parsing the output of svn.